# smartGWT ScrollBar missing when using SectionStack in Window

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I made a window, that contains a SectionStack. When I expend the SectionStackSections the content's vertical lenght is bigger than the vertical lenght of the window. And the problem is, that no ScrollBar appears after expanding the sections. I have read, that the window automatically shows a scroll bar if the components inside the widow are all smartGWT-components.

```
SectionStack sectionStack = new SectionStack();
sectionStack.setVisibilityMode(VisibilityMode.MULTIPLE);
sectionStack.setWidth100();
sectionStack.setHeight100();
Window window = new Window();
window.setHeaderControls(HeaderControls.HEADER_LABEL, view, save, delete);
window.setAutoSize(true);
window.setMaximized(true);
window.setShowCloseButton(false);
window.setShowMinimizeButton(false);
window.addItem(sectionStack);
```

Comment: Please can you share code for `SectionStackSections`. Its not clear from this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Overflow` property to show scroll bar if content doesn't fit into the current window size.

Here `Overflow.AUTO` means :

```
Horizontal and/or vertical scrollbars are displayed only if necessary.
Content that extends beyond the remaining visible area is clipped.
```

Try this

```
window.setOverflow(com.smartgwt.client.types.Overflow.AUTO);
```